# Normal distribution of linear regression coefficients

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I have a problem where I need to explain why the $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ (the estimators of the coefficients) in the standard linear regression are normally distributed when the following scatter plot is given: [image: scatter plot]

Is it because of any assumptions or do I need to look at the trend (which is linear)? Thank you for providing more understanding around this.

Comment: What do you mean by "explain" ? Normal distribution of the coefficients (under the standard assumptionsà is a standard theoretical result obtainable via the "functional delta method".

Comment: The normality is based on the normality assumption of the errors in your model.